# When to initialize infrequently used base class objects

Tags: c#

I have a business object base class which is inherited by my business objects:

```
public class ErrorBase
{
    public bool HasError { get; set; }
    public List<Error> ErrorList { get; set; }

    public ErrorBase()
    {
        HasError = false;
        ErrorList = new List<Error>();
    }
}
```

Can this be optimized? My concern is that `List<Error>` is initialized every time a business object is instantiated, regardless of whether an Error object is ever added.

The only alternative I can think of is initializing `ErrorList = null`, then checking `ErrorList != null` before calling `ErrorList.Add()`, but I'm not sure that performing that check every time before adding an Error is actually an optimization. It certainly adds steps to the process of adding an Error object to the List<>.

Is there another way I'm not thinking of? If not, is one of these approaches considered a best practice?

Comment: Answer really depends on how you are going to use that class. Are you going to add errors to each of this class instances? Some of them will not have errors? Or only several will have errors? How often you will add errors to class? What is expected errors count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: I doubt that creating a new `List<>` object creates enough overhead which has measurable impact on your system so unless you can prove that it's a problem don't worry about it.

That being said: The classic solution to that problem is lazy instantiation. As you have a property already this can be easily achieved by:

```
public class ErrorBase
{
    public bool HasError { get; set; }

    private List<Error> _ErrorList = null;
    public List<Error> ErrorList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ErrorList == null)
            {
                _ErrorList = new List<Error>();
            }
            return _ErrorList;
        }
    }

    public ErrorBase()
    {
        HasError = false;
    }
}
```

If you have multiple threads adding to it then you need to add some locking in the `get` - but then on the other hand `List<>` itself is not thread-safe so I assume that's not the case.

In .NET 4.0 and later you have [`Lazy<>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will make the code a little bit shorter.

Comment: I think using `Lazy<>` doesn't make sense here, since you're avoiding an allocation by making another allocation.